# Hot to select count order by month in sqlalchemy flask

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy

I have this code get error

```
order = db.session.query(func.count(Order.id)).filter(Order.created.like('Mon, 06 Nov 2017 17:21:40 GMT')).scalar()
```

How to get count result order by month?

The created column is timestamp.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find the answer

with the timestamp column in database it works like this

```
query = db.session.query(Order).filter(Order.created >= '2012-10-26')
```

referring to https://gist.github.com/Tukki/3953990
I was try if it's work and it is.